# Как создать проект на slim 2 через composer?

Tags: php, composer, slim

Здравствуйте, не могу никак найти как создать проект slim версии 2, то есть не знаю как указать версию при создании проекта.
Эта команда создает проект на slim 3 (последней версии)

php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton mysitename

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так добавляет последний релиз из ветки 2.x

```
composer require slim/slim "^2.0"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создать проект на версии 2.6.2

```
composer create-project slim/slim=2.6.2 super-project --prefer-dist
```

Comment: Да, так он скачивает сам фреймворк, но я бы очень хотел создать "скелет проекта", как в официальной документации версии 3

Comment: Обновил свой пост, создать проект на версии 2.6.2